# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 when adding FaceBook Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ios5.1

I have the following **failed code** when i run my application **on iPhone 5.1** simulator. My app runs smoothly before i add in the Facebook Connect into my application.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBCreateNonRetainingArray", referenced from:
      -[FBSession initWithKey:secret:getSessionProxy:] in FBSession.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

May I know what can i do to get rid of this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287915/linking-error-in-xcode   u can navigate to this link.

Comment: I have read the post, but none of the answers can help. Thanks

Comment: @Clarence did you find solution? i have the same error with linker in new FacebookSDK 3.0

Comment: Sorry I still cannot solve the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things that usually get rid of that error.

1) go to: target > build phases > link binary with library -- make sure you've added the correct framework
2) go to: target > build phases > compile sources -- add any implementation files that are in your program but do not appear in that list.

Those two steps usually fix that kind of error.